# Multiple Python Versions on Ubuntu 15.10 Causing Problems

Tags: package-management, python, 15.10, python3, pip

I have a hosted server running Ubuntu 15.10, as I use Python 3.6 on my development machine I installed that (wget URL, configure, make, make install etc), this is the point I realised that Ubuntu already had Python 3.4.3 already installed and my life was becoming complicated.

The first symptom of having multiple versions was getting pip to behave, I had a lot of trouble and ended up removing the Ubuntu version of Python and reinstalling it. This seemed to fix things (mostly), but python3 now is linked to my python 3.6.0 install, but pip3 is linked to the 3.4.3 version.

If I start python with python3.4 then it loads the 3.4.3 and I can use it with the packages I have downloaded (primarily MySQLdb (the fork for 3x Python)).

All the above is obviously not ideal, but I thought since it works I will keep testing my setup. The problem is that when the www-data user runs python3.4 it cannot find the packages; I presume it is looking in the wrong place.

Ideally I would like to get rid of Python3.6.0 and just use the native bundled 3.4.3. The multiple installs seem to be causing pip (and me) a lot of confusion.

Comment: Try using `make` to uninstall it that should get rid of it. Run `sudo make uninstall` from the install directory .

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't appear to include an uninstall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All self compiled packages almost always goes in /usr/local/ unless you change the install PATH or if the developers have other non standard things like /opt/ as default.

I assume there's a /usr/local/bin/python3 which you can rename to e.g. /usr/local/bin/python3.6.0 and that might fix it all already.

Can you do a :

```
find /usr/ -iname "python3"
```

I suggest to try :

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.6.0
```

It is possible that "bash" still "thinks" that python3 is in /usr/local/bin/ while you have it in /usr/bin/python3 
You can log out and log in again, and try again.

Comment: Running the above outputs:

/usr/lib/python3
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/python3
/usr/share/python3
/usr/share/doc/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
$

Comment: Looking in just the /usr/local/bin I see the following:

$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ ls
2to3  2to3-3.6  idle3  idle3.6  pip  pip3  pip3.4  pydoc3  pydoc3.6  python3  python3-config  python3.6  python3.6-config  python3.6m  python3.6m-config  pyvenv  pyvenv-3.6

Comment: That did it - I had to uninstall and reinstall my packages with pip to sort them out, but now all is well; thanks!